# What healthy foods won't effect my cardio

Tags: cardio, health

What healthy types of foods would be healthy enough for me to keep running my long distances and not negativity effect my running?

Comment: Can you share more of what your current situation is? What are you currently eating, and how rigorously are you training?

Comment: I have been eating junk food from time to time and I wanted to know if I start eating more healthier would that help me run long or faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, assuming you're not a good collegiate or elite athlete, as long as you're not eating McDonald's every day, your running won't be affected as much as you might think. Eating well will help you feel better, perform better, and be healthier, but most food will be just fine to sustain consistent running.

However, you are probably interested in how to eat well to maximize your performance. In general, it's important to:

- avoid fried food
- drink a lot of water (do this in small, frequent amounts)
- make sure you're getting iron, vitamin D, and calcium - eat dairy and red meat for these
- eat a lot of fruit
- eat within 15 - 30 minutes of finishing a run or workout. Eating food prompts your body to switch from a catabolic state (breaking energy sources down) to an anabolic state (repairing muscles, adapting).

Most importantly, figure out what's right for you. Tweak how, when, how much, and how frequently you eat until it works best for you.